# ScrollPane and height

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have the following problem. I am carrying a child with a JPanel Array I get in a query and the father JPanel from the core. What I needed was to add a JPanel scroll my son and it succeeds but strangely can handle its width but not its height and does not grow. To which I can understand but fails them a picture. And the code I use is as follows:

```
    JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(panelPrincipal);
    jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (1000, 5000)); // This is a test hehe   
    this.add(jScrollPane1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I leave a URL of the image due to my reputation can not post it. http://goo.gl/DOUxZj

Comment: `ScrollPane and height` == `Dimension` from `panelPrincipal`, added to `jScrollPane1`, schrinked by `jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (1000, 5000)); // This is a test hehe`, I'm sure that true is in commented part (`// This is a test hehe`), for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did not understand much you need

Comment: 5000, is way too large for the height of a component. Specify a reasonable height and then pack() the frame before you make the frame visible. The scrollbars will appear when required based on the preferred size of the panel added to the scrollpane.

Comment: @camickr Hi, thanks for your answer, that 5000 was just an example, but my problem and solved it this way, JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(panelPrincipal,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);